# Set and get a static variable from two different classes in Java

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, overwrite

Lets say I have 3 Classes: `A`, `Data`, and `B`

I pass a variable from class `A` which sets that passed variable to a private variable in class `Data`.

Then in class `B`, I want to call that specific variable which has been changed.

So I do

```
Data data = new Data();
data.getVariable();
```

It will then return null, since in class `Data` I initialize variables to nothing (ex: `int v;`), and I think that class `B` is initializing a brand new class and resetting the values to default, but I don't know how to fix this.

I know that the variable is setting properly because in class `A` if I do `data.getVariable()` it will print the variable that was set.

Class `A`:

```
Data data = new Data();
int d = 1;
data.setVariable(d);
```

Class `Data`:

```
private static int b;

public void setVariable(int s)
{
    b = s;
}

public int getVariable()
{
    return b;
}
```

Class `B`:

```
Data data = new Data();
private int v; 

v = data.getVariable();
System.out.println(v);
```

This will print out 0 instead of the actual value

Comment: Please provide your code, not just descriptions of your classes.

Comment: My code for all 3  classes is over 800 lines long, so I just made up what I currently test in it... I don't know what extends does or not, so if you could explain better and if it would solve my solution, then I will try it.

Comment: If I Do extends Data in class B, it still doesn't work

Comment: The class B definition would not ever compile. Show the code please.

Comment: All it is missing is public class..

Comment: Please post your `main` method

Comment: You need to either (a) reference the same instance, or (b) make the variable static.

Comment: Are you sure that your request are happening in the correct order? You are sure that class A is setting the variable, before class B reads it?

Comment: My problem was assigning the variables after static.

Comment: I think I did the same thing as was suggested in the accepted answer but I still get different values for the static variable. I have a variable called `x` in a class `SharedUtils` whose default value is `-1` . I have set `SharedUtils.x = 1` at one place but later when I check the value of the variable, it shows the default value of `-1` and not the value I've set it to. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you instantiate a `Data` object in class A, and instantiate another `Data` object in class B, they are *two different instances* of the `Data` class.  They both instantiate `d` to 0 by default.  You then call `setVariable` on the instance in class A and pass it the value of 1; but the instance in class B remains in 0.  In order to change the value of the instance in class B, you would need to call `setVariable` on the instance in class B.

What it seems like you're looking for is a static member.  Static members are the same across all instances of the same class.  Just put the `static` keyword before the method(s) or field(s) that you want to use it.  Static members and fields are typically accessed using the name of the class in which they are declared (i.e. `MyClass.doMethod()`).  For example:

**Class Data (updated):**

```
private static int b;

public static void setVariable(int s)
{
    b = s;
}

public static int getVariable()
{
    return b;
}
```

**Class A**:

```
Data.setVariable(d);
```

**Class B**:

```
v = Data.getVariable();
System.out.println(v);
```

Comment: The methods dont need to be static. He can still use "new" and have the methods non static. The variable is enough

Comment: Even putting static before the methods, it will still give me 0.

Comment: Alright, I seemed to have fixed my problem where I was declaring the variables and assigning them to get the data.

Comment: @Avempace: While technically "correct," I would consider that to be bad design.

Comment: I think I did the same thing. I have a variable called `x` in a class `SharedUtils` whose default value is `-1` . I have set `SharedUtils.x = 1` at one place but later when I check the value of the variable, it shows the default value of `-1` and not the value I've set it to. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Editing - my first suggestion was to use `static` for variable `b`, and the author changed his question adding that suggestion.

It fixes what you are trying to do. I write the example in code that compiles:

```
    public class Demo {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A a = new A();
            B b = new B();
            a.doWhatever();
            b.doSomethingElse();
        }
    }
    class Data {
        private static int b;

        public void setVariable(int s)
        {
            b = s;
        }

        public int getVariable()
        {
            return b;
        }
    }
    class A {
        public void doWhatever() {
            Data data = new Data();
            int d = 1;
            data.setVariable(d);
        }
    }

    class B {
        Data data = new Data();
        private int v; 
        public void doSomethingElse() {
            v = data.getVariable();
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This somehwat works, but when I print out V in Class B, it still displays null. I updated the main code again with static.

Comment: I am a bit confused. How can it print "null"? it is an integer

Comment: Ok, well I was making an example, in mine it is a string but it doesn't matter anyway since the integer will print out 0 instead of the actual value, my bad. So just replace null with 0.

Comment: It displays 0, not null. 0 is not the correct value anyway, it should be displaying 6. I can't print out the whole code because its way to long.

Comment: Not sure then, I looked over what I have and it is doing the exact same thing. I'll keep looking over yours to see if I am missing something. Thanks for the help